# Saving Multiple Relationships via checkboxes in a Channel Form

Tags: safecracker, relationships, channel-form

I have relationships field `Foo` where people can have more than one entry, basically a multiple relationships field.

I am not using `{field:foo}` to output my form field. Instead I am using multiple checkboxes to save the multiple relationships.

What is the proper way to do this?

Is there a native way to do this or do I have to resort to implementing a function in extensions to work them out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To output the information this worked for me:

```
<p class="grid-row"><em>Fav Style:</em><span>{options:member_favourite_drinks}{if selected}{option_name},{/if}{/options:member_favourite_drinks}</span></p>
```

... and to have this in a select list:

```
{custom_fields}
     {if field_name=="member_favourite_drinks"}
            <select id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}[data][]" multiple="multiple">
                  <option value="">Select...</option>
                  {options}
                      <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
                  {/options}
             </select>
     {/if}
{/custom_fields}
```

... checkboxes will need an embed inside the form:

```
{embed="_embeds/.drinks-list"}
```

contents would be:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="drinks" order="title" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}
    <div class="form-item form-item-checkbox form-item-small">
            <label for="member_favourite_drinks_{count}">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="member_favourite_drinks[data][]" value="{entry_id}" id="member_favourite_drinks_{count}">
        <span>{title}</span>
    </label>
</div>{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This snippet, `name="member_favourite_drinks[data][]"`, was what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice solution, how are the checkboxes checked? (when editing)

Comment: @GDmac I had to make a custom plugin for it. The channel entries solution has no way of knowing which values are selected by itself.

Comment: You could pass the entry_id to the embed, and try using the parents tag with the embed:entry_id. If it is a match, just output checked or checked="checked".