# Channel Form : Passing data into a Playa or Relationship field

Tags: channel-entries, playa, members, channel-form

I need to allow users the ability to create an entry via the front end hence I'm using Channel Form.

In the CP I have set up several custom fields in this channel to be either a Playa field or a Relationship field.

In the Channel form page I am building SELECT statements by looping through a channel:entries tag building the value to be the entry_id and the text to be the title.

When I save the form the value of these fields are not being saved to either of the playa or relationship fields.

Is it possible to do this? Should I be passing in some other value other than the entry_id? I have the SELECT names set to the name of the custom field.

Oh and as an added complication the user is also selecting one of the site members. Currently I'm just saving the member_id to a text field so it's just showing up as a number. Is there any plugins I could use that would allow the editor in the CP to see the members name rather than their ID?

Comment: You've really asked 2 separate questions, maybe move the member_id part to a new question. For the relationship in channel form, try using {field:your_relationship_field_name} in the channel form, then look at the html that's generated on the front end. This should help see how the Relationship field is formatted. See this post for some examples with checkboxes: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14340/saving-multiple-relationships-via-checkboxes-in-a-channel-form

Comment: Thank you, that link you provided had the answer. Updating the field name to name="custom_field_name[data][]" is what I needed.

Comment: Hi Romans, I have had to change my custom field from EE's native Relationship field to one using Playa. Unfortunately I am now getting an error message when submitting the form. I have the field set as required and submitting the form throws an error. Do you know what syntax I require specifically for a Playa field? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the field name to name="custom_field_name[data][]" was the solution:

```
<select class="" name="log_skill[data][]" id="log_skill">
```